# A word that describes extreme heat

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm looking of a term or adjective for extremely high temperatures. 
One that can describe the temperature of the sun or the hottest thing in the universe.

Words like *conflagrant* or *Blaze* doesn't fit what I want.

Comment: Astronomical "high temperatures" (inside stars, at the time of the Big Bang, etc.) are *way* outside normal human experience. Within the range of temperatures that make sense to us, it's natural enough to use words linked to things like ***burning*** - but that's a feature of "chemistry", which doesn't really mean anything when the energy levels are so high that even ***atoms*** can't exist.

Comment: ...note that although it's confined to a very small space, the Large Hadron Collider at Cerne can reach energy levels that could be expressed as [5.5 TRILLION degrees Celsius!](https://www.seeker.com/lhc-smashes-highest-man-made-temperature-record-1765929082.html) That's probably *way* hotter than the inside of any star (and the *surface* of our sun is relatively "cool" at under 6000 degrees C).

Comment: The Sun is a miasma / Of **incandescent** plasma.

Comment: @AE: I'm speaking out above my pay grade here, but I note the (Latin) root of ***incandescent*** essentially means ***white-hot***. And I think it's an inevitable consequence of terrestrial biology that sunlight = white light = light emitted by something that's around 6000° C. The concept of the "colour" of electromagnetic radiation  coming from places much hotter than that (such as the *centre* of the Sun, at 15,000,000° C) seems effectively meaningless, so even that "metaphoric" usage falls way short of the relevant energy levels.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [torrid](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/torrid) is what you are looking for. It happens to be one of my favorite words.

This is another reliable source for the definition:[image]

Comment: I think that OP refers to the temperature of the sun itself.

Comment: See the picture that was just uploaded.

Comment: One of Merriam-Webster’s definitions for “torrid” is “giving off intense heat.”

Comment: The Tropics are torrid, the Sun is something else entirely.

Comment: “Torrid” can be used to refer to heat directly caused by the sun. Or it can be used to denote something that is extremely hot i.e. not necessarily due to the sun.